# Write PDF file obtained via AJAX into browser window

Tags: xml, pdf, post, httprequest

I'm writing a light-weight client-side JS-based UI that goes through a REST API to generate a PDF doc on a server.  The user completes a form, the contents are compiled into an XML string by the client, then the whole thing gets posted to the server via AJAX, and a PDF is returned. Question is how do I get the PDF to the user (inline,  download, whatever)?

I can't use forms (I think) because the API doesn't take key value pairs and  instead expects an XML post.

Opening a new window with JS doesn't seem to work because the headers get sent before I can write my PDF string.

I've seen this: http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/ but that seems overkill - all I want is the user to get access to the pdf.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pdfObject](http://pdfobject.com/), it´s is a nice javascript library for dynamically embedding PDF
into HTML documents.